# UIScrollView and UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, scroll, uiscrollview

I'm developing a profile screen for my app. I have a UIScrollView and inside:
 - UIView for avatar and username on top
 - UIView with this segmented control https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu inside and two UITableViewController in PageMenu.

Now, I would like to scroll the UIScrollView and when the avatar UIView on top is off screen, the scroll is continued by the UITableViewController. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pattern for complex scroll views which you can try, is to make one transparent view atop of the screen with gesture recognizer that will catch user touches, and scrollviews with actual data and views (scrollView with avatar and tableView) bellow this view. Your viewController should receive touch events, and decide how to pass this events to scrollViews, in your case - based on avatarScrollView's contentOffset.